# How can I fetch record drom database in edit view In Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

In my edit view I have code like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-12">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastName" class="form-control form-control-line" value="{{$profile->personal_detail['last_name']}}" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-12">Department</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <select class="custom-select form-control col-md-11" id="department" name="department">{{ $profile->personal_profile['department'] }}
            @foreach($listDepartment as $departmentList){
                <option value='{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}'>{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}</option>
            }
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In edit view my last name field it gives me last name from database, in department it display me drop down of department but I want that inserted name of department in that field.

how can i get it??

I have other drop down like this

```
<div class="row">
<label class="col-md-6"><b> Mode </b></label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<select class="custom-select form-control col-md-12" name="mode" id="mode" required>
   <option value=""> --- Select Interciew Mode --- </option>
   <option value="telephonic">Telephonic</option>
   <option value="facetoface">Face 2 face</option>
   <option value="skype">Skype</option>
</select>
</div>
</div><hr>
```

This is my controller

```
public function candidateDetail($id)
    {
        $empDetails = User::all();
        $candidateDetail = EmployeeHire::find($id);

        $interview = [
            '' => '--- Select Interciew Mode ---',
            'telephonic' => 'Telephonic',
            'facetoface' => 'Face 2 face',
            'skype' => 'Skype'
        ];

        return view('pages.candidatedetails', compact('id', 'candidateDetail', 'empDetails', 'interview'));
    }
```

Comment: in the <option> use if candition to check department and `echo 'selected` if it is equal to the one in the profile

Comment: Will you please explain more???
my problem is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m7we.png)
Can't get the value in dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in your `foreach` if the value of `nameOfDepartment` match the one from your user.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-12">Department</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <select class="custom-select form-control col-md-11" id="department" name="department">
            @foreach($listDepartment as $departmentList)
                @if ($profile->personal_profile['department'] == $departmentList->nameOfDepartment)
                    <option value="{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}" selected="selected">{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}</option>
                @else
                    <option value="{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}">{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}</option>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

For your second select field, create an array with all possible values in your controller.

```
$interview = [
    '' => '--- Select Interciew Mode ---',
    'telephonic' => 'Telephonic',
    'facetoface' => 'Face 2 face',
    'skype' => 'Skype'
];
```

Then you can do the same as your previous select :

```
<select class="custom-select form-control col-md-12" name="mode" id="mode" required>
    @foreach($interview as $key => $name)
        @if ($profile->personal_profile['interview'] == $key)
            <option value="{{ $key }}" selected="selected">{{ $name }}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $name }}</option>
        @endif
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I have updated my question.. Will you please help me sir?

Comment: umm heya personal profile variable is not use here, I've updated my controller function in question

Comment: Change `$profile->personal_profile['interview']` by the current value you have

Comment: heyaa @fdehanne
will you please help in my this problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231229/how-can-i-update-image-in-edit-view-in-laravel