# How can I update image in edit view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

In laravel I have a field in my edit view named Profile Picture, whenever I click On edit button I got all the values from database in edit view but I don't get image, And If whenever I click on submit button everytime I have to upload image without that I can't process further I want If I not upload new image then form will automatic consider old profile pic

my blade file is like

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="photo">Profile Picture :<span class="danger">*</span> </label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @foreach ($empProfilePic as $empProfilePicture)
                    @if($employee->id == $empProfilePicture->id)
                        <img src="uploads/images/{{ $empProfilePicture->file }}" id="profile-img-tag" height="100" width="100">
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller File

```
 public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $employee = User::find($id);
        //Get inputs for personal detail
        $firstName = $request->get('firstName');
        $middleName = $request->get('middleName');
        $lastName = $request->get('lastName');
        $gender = $request->get('gender');
        $city = $request->get('city');
        $state = $request->get('state');
        $localAddress = $request->get('localAddress');
        $permanentAddress = $request->get('permanentAddress');
        $personalEmail = $request->get('personalEmail');
        $mobileNumber = $request->get('mobileNumber');
        $companyEmail = $request->get('companyEmail');
        $empId = $request->get('empId');
        $department = $request->get('department');
        $designation = $request->get('designation');
        $status = $request->get('status');
        $totalExperience = $request->get('totalExperience');
        $aboutMe = $request->get('aboutMe');
        $roleName = $request->get('role');
        $role = $request->get('role');

        if ($role == 'hr') 
        {
            $role = '5c8a51ed650fbd5398503043';
        }
        else 
        {
            $role = '5c8a51ed650fbd5398503044';    
        }


        // //Store Image In Folder
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('uploads/images', $name);

        if (file_exists(public_path($name =  $file->getClientOriginalName()))) 
        {
            unlink(public_path($name));
        };


        $accountHolderName = $request->get('accountHolderName');
        $accountNumber = $request->get('accountNumber');
        $bankName = $request->get('bankName');
        $ifscCode = $request->get('ifsc_code');
        $panNumber = $request->get('panNumber');
        $branchName = $request->get('branchName');


        //Enter in database
        $employee->role_id = $role;
        $employee->role_name = $roleName;
        $employee->username = $firstName;

        //Update Image
        $employee->file = $name;
        $employee->personal_email = $personalEmail;
        $employee->company_email = $companyEmail;
        $employee->status = $status;

        $personalDetail = ([
            'emp_id' => $empId,
            'first_name' => $firstName,
            'middle_name' => $middleName,
            'last_name' => $lastName,
            'gender' => $gender,
            'city' => $city,
            'state' => $state,
            'local_address' => $localAddress,
            'permanent_address' => $permanentAddress,
            'personal_email' => $personalEmail,
            'mobile_number' => $mobileNumber,
            'department' => $department,
            'designation' => $designation,
            'total_experience' => $totalExperience,
            'about_me' => $aboutMe,
        ]);

        $bankDetail = ([
            'account_holder_name' => $accountHolderName,
            'account_number' => $accountNumber,
            'bank_name' => $bankName,
            'ifsc_code' => $ifscCode,
            'pan_number' => $panNumber,
            'branch_name' => $branchName,
        ]);

        $employee->status = $status;
        $employee->personal_detail = $personalDetail;
        $employee->bank_detail = $bankDetail;

        $employee->save();

        return redirect('list-of-employees')->with('Success', 'Data Updated Successfully!');
    }
```

Will anyone will help, Thank you in advance

Comment: Please paste your model code.

Comment: you mean code of blade.php file ?

Comment: Add a check in controller to upload image only if request contains the image.

Comment: No, your model where your table connected

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag?

Comment: I am using mongodb and I updated the code

Comment: yes I have that `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In controller:

Code for update file:

Its update only when you select a file for the update.

Here I use the Employee model you can replace with your model

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

     $employee = Employee::find($id);

     if($request->file != ''){        
          $path = public_path().'/uploads/images/';

          //code for remove old file
          if($employee->file != ''  && $employee->file != null){
               $file_old = $path.$employee->file;
               unlink($file_old);
          }

          //upload new file
          $file = $request->file;
          $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move($path, $filename);

          //for update in table
          $employee->update(['file' => $filename]);
     }
}
```

Comment: But there is a problem If I submit my edit form without uploading any image it will remove my old image
Like https://ibb.co/wdR4gHk

Comment: What if i don't upload new image than it will automatically take old picture as it is

Comment: this will work like when I upload new image, old image will unlink new image store in folder too, but it can't insert in database

Comment: @amindevloper I have updated my code for the insert file name in the database.

Comment: It insert in database store in file too, but can't display

Answer (score 3):

Try this. If you get the file in post method, only then set the file variable of an employee.

```
        // //Store Image In Folder
        if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('uploads/images', $name);

            if (file_exists(public_path($name =  $file->getClientOriginalName()))) 
            {
                unlink(public_path($name));
            };
            //Update Image
            $employee->file = $name;
        }

        //Enter in database
        $employee->role_id = $role;
        $employee->role_name = $roleName;
        $employee->username = $firstName;
```

Comment: There is 1 issue,yes it works , if i upload new pic it will insert and work properly, But when I submit the form without inserting new image it will show error like `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null`

Comment: You are welcome. you can use this condition where you will not get an error of "call on null". `if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']))`

Answer (score 0):

Make the image input optional (don't add required) on the blade file and on the validation (controller) then check before updating as:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
      // Perform image update
}
```